# Calling a hard-coded existing method with Reflection.Emit in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm designing a .NET-Type at runtime by using the Reflection.Emit-Namespace.
Currently, I'm about to generate a method which invokes an already existing method in the generating class:

```vb
Dim AssemblyBuilder As AssemblyBuilder = Nothing
Dim ModuleBuilder As ModuleBuilder = Nothing
Dim TypeBuilder As TypeBuilder = Nothing

Dim MethodBuilder As MethodBuilder
Dim ReturnType As Type = Nothing

AssemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(New AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave)

ModuleBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicAsssembly", "DynamicAssembly.dll")
TypeBuilder = ModuleBuilder.DefineType("DynamicType")

MethodBuilder = TypeBuilder.DefineMethod("Do", MethodAttributes.Public, Nothing, Nothing)
```

The above works.

```vb
MethodBuilder.GetILGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, Me.GetType.GetMethod("DisplayString"), Nothing)
MethodBuilder.GetILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

ReturnType = TypeBuilder.CreateType()
Activator.CreateInstance(ReturnType)
```

This is want I want to do in general: Invoking a method which is located in the executing class itself. But when calling the following, an exeception is thrown.

```vb
ReturnType.GetMethod("Do").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(ReturnType), Nothing)
```

The inner exception is (something like): InvalidProgramException, "The Common Language Runtime has found an invalid program."

If I replace the lines from above in which I emit the call by e.g.

```vb
MethodBuilder.GetILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "test")
MethodBuilder.GetILGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, GetType(System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox).GetMethod("Show", {GetType(String)}), {GetType(String)})
MethodBuilder.GetILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Pop)
```

it works fine.

I suppose there occures a problem because the executing assembly types and their members are not accessible, but is that true, and what may I change to get it running?

Thanks

Momo

Comment: What's the signature of the `DisplayString` method?

Answer (score 0):

Is `DisplayString` a static method (`MessageBox.Show`  is)?

If not you are going to need an instance to call the method on

*please for give my mangeled VB, its been quite a while ;)*

```
dim fieldBuilder as FieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(
                "o", Me.GetType(),
                 FieldAttributes.InitOnly | FieldAttributes.Private);


dim constructor as ConstructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
                MethodAttributes.Public |
                MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
                MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,
                CallingConventions.Standard, new[] { Me.GetType() });

//Make tho CTOR for the dynamic type, it needs to take an argument of the
//instance to call the method on (in this case it will be Me)

dim il as ILGenerator = constructor.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseCtor);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Make the method
il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, 'test');

il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, Me.GetType.GetMethod ...
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

hope this helps.

One of the best ways to learn what need to emit is to use write the class as you normally would, then use `IL DASM` on it, then you can copy the OpCodes from that.

Comment: Many thanks! I did forget that I need to get an instance from my class. I just tried it by making it a static (shared) method and it worked. When I have some more time, I will try to call an instance method. Thanks for the tip with ILDASM. I already did it, but I always find it hard to understand what is happening there...